# Is it possible to use Include with a string value of the field name?

Tags: c#, lambda, csom

1. I want to load an SharePoint Project Server Project using CSOM

   ```
   var proj = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Projects
           .Where(p => p.Id == projGuid)
           .Include(p => p.Id, p => p.Name));

   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   ```
2. I needed the `Include()` to be dynamic so I did this:

   ```
   Expression<Func<PublishedTask, object>>[] funcArray 
               = new Expression<Func<PublishedTask, object>>[2];

       funcArray[0] = p => p.Name;
       funcArray[1] = p => p.Id;

   var proj = ctx.LoadQuery(ctx.Projects
           .Where(p => p.Id == projGuid)
           .Include(funcArray));

   ctx.ExecuteQuery();
   ```
3. Now I am only get the information of which property has to be loaded from a String, so I tried something like this:

   ```
   funcArray[0] = p => p.GetType().GetProperty("Name");
   funcArray[1] = p => p.GetType().GetProperty("Id");
   ```

That doesn't work and I am not quite sure If I am doing it right or if it is even possible to do it.

Comment: There is an `Include` overload which accepts string. You can use that if you already have property names as strings. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696450(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of passing an array of functions, you can pass a comma separated string and use some Linq to split them and include each one in query:

```
var includeFields = "Name,Id";

var proj = ctx.Projects.GetByGuid(projGuid);

foreach (var fieldName in includeFields.Split(','))
{
    ctx.Load(proj, includes => includes[fieldName]);
}

ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can also use the method "GetByGuid" instead of a Linq Where.

Comment: With your code I get the error on the 3rd line `...q.Include(p)...` p: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.PublishedProject, object>>' do I need to include something to be able to use the overload from `Include()`? It only shows me the option to use Include with an array.

Comment: Which version of Entity Framework are you using? Core or 6?

Comment: try adding: "using System.Linq.Expressions;" to your document

Comment: I don't know. I looked in Visual Studio in the Project Properties and the only thing I could find about Framework was: Application > Target Framework : .Net Framework 4.5. Is that what you meant? Should I change it to 4.6? I am already using  "using System.Linq.Expressions;"

Comment: @ceferrari They're not  using EF at all.  This is the SharePoint CSOM, as the question says.

Comment: Updated my answer. @socramm please try again

Comment: @ceferrari Unfortunately it didn't work "InvalidQueryExpressionException: The query expression '.......' is not supported."

Comment: @socramm Updated again. I'm confident it will work now.